# SQL syntax error with MySQL and PHP. 'option FROM poll_maker_options WHERE poll_id = 3'

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have this query:

```
SELECT votes, option 
  FROM poll_maker_options 
 WHERE poll_id = " . $row['poll_id']
```

I see nothing wrong with that but I get the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option FROM poll_maker_options WHERE poll_id = 3' at line 1

Thank you for any help. I hope I'm not blind like yesterday when I couldn't spot a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"option" is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL, so either change the field name, or surround it with backticks in all the queries it's used in:

```
SELECT votes, `option` FROM ...
```